# Rasterizing and summing all polygons in a shapefile

Tags: python, raster, shapefile, rasterio, rasterize

I am trying to take a shapefile with 5 polygons, rasterize each of them into a raster file, and then sum all of those rasters. I have been trying to accomplish this in python using `rasterio` and `geocube`, but have encountered some issues where my raster files are just not aligned, preventing me from carrying out the sum. I will detail all of my data and steps below.

Data source: I am using this shapefile containing the 5 boroughs of NYC: https://data.cityofnewyork.us/City-Government/Borough-Boundaries/tqmj-j8zm

First, I want to assign a made-up example "test_value" to each polygon/borough, this can be whatever. I want to first rasterize each polygon, so that I have a separate raster file for each rasterized polygon isolated. This means that I would have one raster file that just has Manhattan rasterized, as if it were the only borough in the city, and then the next raster file having just Brooklyn rasterized, as if it were the only borough in the city, etc. Here is the code I am using to accomplish this:

```
polygons = gpd.read_file('Boroughs_Test/Boroughs.shp')
polygon_IDs = polygons['ID'].tolist()

for i in polygon_IDs:
    x = polygons.loc[polygons['ID'] == i]
    vector_fn = x
    out_grid = make_geocube(
        vector_data=vector_fn,
        measurements=["test_value"],
        resolution=(-25, 25),
        fill=-9999,
    )
    out_grid["test_value"].rio.to_raster(str(i) + "_Output_Raster.tif")
```

This works, and I receive a separate raster file for each borough. For example here is Manhattan:
[image]

and here is Bronx:
[image]

And then I just view all 5 rasters at once to make up the whole city:
[image]

So, now each rasterized polygon has it own unique "test_value" value. I want to add all of these "test_value" values up across all of the rasters. So here is what I am trying to use to sum all of these raster layers up:

```
for raster in folder:
    blank_raster + raster
    with rasterio.open('Result_raster_NYC.tif', 'w', **result_profile) as dst:
        dst.write(result_array, indexes=[1])
```

Where essentially I loop through each borough raster in my directory, and keep adding them to a blank raster of all 0s. However, I am suspicious that this would be the correct approach, and I believe I am missing some important considerations that would need to be used for calculations with rasterio.

How can I augment my code so that I can sum all of the raster layers in my directory? These raster layers only have one band that has the "test_values" in it, if that needs to be specified. The final product would just look the same as the full NYC map above, but with each rasterized borough containing its own pixel values of its corresponding "test_value" value, at different shades of grey.

Comment: To anyone looking for the answer to this:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/419419/rasterize-and-sum-polygons-in-python/438884#438884